# read CSV file Save output to LIST using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a sample CSV file as follows

1. 1,A
2. 2,B
3. 3,C

Code:

```
var query = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
            .Select(record => record.Split(','))
            .Select(tokens => new { clearNum = tokens[0], MPID = tokens[1] });

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.clearNum, item.MPID);
}
```

I am able to print the items.

I need to send the output of LINQ query to LIST

public class icSASList
    {
        public string ClearNum { get; set; }
        public string MPID { get; set; }
    }

List clearList =  new List;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering the accepted answer, I'd like to suggest a solution that requires less object initializations. If the list is large, this will make a difference.

```
var query = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
.Select(record => record.Split(','))
.Select(tokens => new icSASList(){ ClearNum = tokens[0], MPID = tokens[1] }); 

var clearList = query.ToList();
```

Oh, yeah, using `record.Split(',')` is naive - it's normally allowed to have commas in " (quoted) fields, which will break your program. Better use something like http://www.filehelpers.com/.

Comment: I chose previous poster as answer because it worked for me , I will give a shot to you suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vladislav Zorov , your solution works and gives desired result

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried compiling it but I think you want something like this?

```
var clearList = query.Select(x=>new icSASList(){ClearNum = x.clearNum, MPID = x.MPID}).ToList();
```